# How do I get the length of a String in Swift3 on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, swift3

How do I get the length of a `String` in 'Swift3' on macOS?

This used to work in Swift2:

```
if purchaseDateString.length == 0 {
     purchaseDateString = "n/a"
}
```

What is Swift3 equivalent for finding String's length.

UPDATE

There are answers to this question as Martin points out. The referred question has 30 answers. However, as far as I can tell, none of them relate specifically to Swift3. I could be wrong..

Comment: What is the type of `purchaseDateString`? Option-click on it to find out.

Comment: It is `string.characters.count` since Swift 2. Your above code does *not* work in Swift 2.

Comment: Checking for an empty string can also be done with `if string.isEmpty { }`, in Swift 2 and 3.

Comment: Re your edit: *"none of them relate specifically to Swift3"* – that's because your problem is not specifically to Swift 3. As I said, nothing changed between Swift 2 and 3 with respect to this question. All Swift 2 answers in that Q&A are still valid.

Comment: ok. in fact though, my code was working up to and including Xcode 8, beta 5. Anyway, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Have you try `characters.count`

```
if purchaseDateString.characters.count == 0 {
     purchaseDateString = "n/a"
}
```

**Edit:-** As of in Swift 3.2 and Swift 4 String is Collection type so you can directly use `count` property on String.

```
if purchaseDateString.count == 0 {
     purchaseDateString = "n/a"
}
```

Comment: This seems to be changing in Swift 4. Using my example, now it's simply `purchaseDateString.count`

Comment: Edit answer with Swift 4